# if checkbox not checked don't send form with submit input type=image

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I need to disable submission of this form (and ideally send an alert message with javascript when clicked) when the checkbox is not checked.

I found many solutions for classical submit buttons, but none of them works with an image submit. All the time I'm able to display error messages but still the form is being sent.

Do you have any idea how can I solve this? Thank you

```
<form method="POST" name="paypal" action="">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox"/> 
<label for="checkbox" class="agree">I accept the</label> <a href="#" target="_blank">conditions</a>
<input type="image" name="submit" src="http://www.example.com/paypal.png">
</form>
```

Comment: It doesn't matter what element triggers the submit as long as you're listening to the correct event. I.E `$('form').on('submit',function(){});`

Comment: Show us the javascript code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just listen to submit event on the form, check all you have to and return true if the form is correct and false if it's not. If you return false the form should not be submitted.

```
$('form[name="paypal"]').submit(function () {
    if (invalid) {
        alert("Some of the fields are not valid.");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<form method="POST" name="paypal" action="" onsubmit="return (function() { if (!document.getElementById('checkbox').checked) { alert('You must accept the conditions');return false; }})()">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox"/> 
<label for="checkbox" class="agree">I accept the</label> <a href="#" target="_blank">conditions</a>
<input type="image" name="submit" src="http://www.example.com/paypal.png">
</form>
```

I added an onsubmit event handler which runs a function that determines if the checkbox is checked and if it is not we show an alert and return false preventing the form from being submitted.

Answer (score 0):

when the image is clicked, check if the checkbox is checked.

```
jQuery('input[name="submit"]').on('click', function(){
      var accept = jQuery('input[name="checkbox"]').is(":checked");
      if(accept == false){
        alert("you did not accept the terms");
        return false;
      }
      if(accept == true){
        //submit form
      }
    });
```